# How to handle negative values in a chess transposition table hash function?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, chess

I am writing a chess engine in Java. In order to optimize search speed, I implemented a [transposition table](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Transposition_Table) to store the results of previous searches. In transposition tables the position is typically represented as a 64-bit [Zobrist hash](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Zobrist_Hashing).

However, since this is far too large to use as the index to the array containing the table values, chess engines use another hashing function to return a smaller number that can serve as the index. From what I have read online, the formula commonly used for this second hash function is:

`index = zobristKey % entries.size`

My problem is that, in Java I use the (signed) long for my zobrist key, meaning that the resulting index will sometimes have a negative value, which cannot be used as an array index. I currently get around this by calling Math.abs(index), but as a result I see a lot of hash table collisions.

My general understanding of hash functions is not so strong, and I'm sure that I'm missing something in my current implementation. For any chess engine programmers/Java experts, what is the correct way to calculate a hash table index for a transposition table like this?

My hash function to create the hash table index from the Zobrist key:

`private int getIndex(long zobristKey) { return Math.abs(Long.valueOf(zobristKey % entries.length).intValue()); }`

Comment: If `Math.abs` generates a lot of collisions, there is no alternative that won't.

Answer (score 0):

If `Math.abs` generates a lot of collisions, there is no alternative that won't.

With that said, applying `& Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of `Math.abs` would more effectively avoid the edge case where the key is `Long.MIN_VALUE`, where `Math.abs` would return a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

`x % n` doesn't actually compute `x mod n`, it computes the remainder of `x / n`. The latter often matches the former, but not always.

You probably want to use `Math.floorMod(x, n)` instead.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377258/7708